# Is there an incidental word for 'exchange'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider the following sentence.

*The movie Freaky Friday depicts two people exchanging bodies with each other.*

In that sentence, the verb *exchanging* seems volitional. However, the movie depicts two people incidentally exchanging (for lack of a better word) bodies.

I cannot think of an equivalent incidental verb. Words such as *trade* and *swap* both seem to express volitional acts.

Is there an incidental verb equivalent to *exchange*?

Thank you.

-Hal

Comment: You could use the passive. That's one of the things it's good for.

Comment: @StoneyB Exactly my thought. Nothing much else emerges from a list of synonyms. But you could try: *Two people with transposed bodies*.

Comment: Google claims over 30,000 instances of [*"two people **switch** bodies"*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22two+people+switch+bodies%22&oq=%22two+people+switch+bodies%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.15561569j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), but only 278 for [*"two people **exchange** bodies"*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22two+people+exchange+bodies%22&oq=%22two+people+exchange+bodies%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.15689661j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). I know which verb ***I'd*** use, and apparently a lot of other people think the same.

Comment: Exchange does not, of course, need to have the volitional caveat. An ion exchanger and a heat exchanger are non-sentient.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth good point.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Switch*. Ugh. I should have thought of that. Good call.

Comment: @StoneyB Good point! Thank you. I've mostly eliminated the passive from my writing. Evidently, I threw the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: @Hall: In a somewhat less "surreal" context, [*"two people **swap** jobs"*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22two+people+swap+jobs%22&oq=%22two+people+swap+jobs%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.2489j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) gets 184 hits, where [***switch***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22two+people+switch+jobs%22&oq=%22two+people+switch+jobs%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.147130j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) gets only 9, and ***exchange*** gets none at all. Note that both *switch* and *swap* effectively make *with each other* redundant.

Comment: English verbs should not be held responsible for the belief that the human incorporeal mind/personality/soul/self part is separable from the human corporeal meat part, let alone exchangeable. English doesn't have special verbs for things that are impossible; for this you need theology.

Answer (score 1):

You may feel that **interchange** is less volitional.